# How to handle more than multiple sets of data in R programming?

Tags: r, cut, mean

Ca
    data <- cut(data$Time, breaks=seq(0, max(data$Time)+400, 400))
       by(data$Oxytocin, cuts, mean)

but this would only work for only one person's data....But I have ten people with their own Time and oxytocin data....How would I get their averages simultaneously? Also instead of having this type output :

```
cuts: (0,400]
[1] 0.7
------------------------------------------------------------ 
cuts: (400,800]
[1] 0.805
```

Is there a way I can get a list of those cuts?

Comment: Could you provide an example of your data structure? How are you storing it in R? Knowing that, I think I can help with a simple solution.

Comment: I'm just using ....data=read.delim("clipboard")...the data is from an excel spreadsheet

Comment: Ok, I get it. I need a precise idea of the data structure. Could you run `dump(head(data, 10), "")` and paste output here? Is it possible to share a bit of the data? That would help a lot. If there are confidentiality issues, maybe you could multiply the numbers by random values first.

Comment: I posted a new question about this coz my data format is making things too hard for me....can u check this link and see if it makes any sense to you...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994084/multiple-columns-of-data-and-getting-average-r-program

Comment: Ok, I left a comment there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution using `IRanges` package.

`idx` assumes your data format is `Time`, `data`, `Time`, `data`, ... and so on.. So, it creates indices `1,3,5,...ncol(df)-1`.

`ir1` is the intervals you would want the mean for. It's width is 400. It goes from 0 to max(Time) for each Time column (here columns 1 and 3).

`ir2` is the corresponding Time column of interval width = 1.

Then I get the overlaps of `ir1` with `ir2`, which basically tells me which intervals from ir2 overlap with ir1 (which we want), from which I calculate the mean and output the `data.frame`.

```
idx <- seq(1, ncol(df), by=2)
o <- lapply(idx, function(i) {  
    ir1 <- IRanges(start=seq(0, max(df[[i]]), by=401), width=401)
    ir2 <- IRanges(start=df[[i]], width=1)
    t <- findOverlaps(ir1, ir2)
    d <- data.frame(mean=tapply(df[[i+1]], queryHits(t), mean))
    cbind(as.data.frame(ir1), d)
})

> o
# [[1]]
#   start  end width      mean
# 1     0  400   401 0.6750000
# 2   401  801   401 0.8050000
# 3   802 1202   401 0.8750000
# 4  1203 1603   401 0.2285333

# [[2]]
#   start  end width    mean
# 1     0  400   401 0.73508
# 2   401  801   401 0.13408
# 3   802 1202   401 0.26408
# 4  1203 1603   401 1.06408
# 5  1604 2004   401 3.06408
```

For each `Time` column, you'll get a list with the intervals and mean for that interval.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Arun, but I'm getting an error like this :Error in as.data.frame(ir1) : object 'ir1' not found

Comment: For this data or for another one of your data?

Comment: Do you have `IRanges` package installed and loaded using `library(IRanges)`?

Comment: For both of them....I tried installing it and I got this warning message...package ‘IRanges’ is not available (for R version 2.15.1)

Comment: Sorry I should have mentioned it. Check here on [**how to install**](http://www.bioconductor.org/packages/2.11/bioc/html/IRanges.html). Its part of the bioconductor package.

Comment: hey arun...I got this error when I used the first line of the code...Error in seq.default(1, ncol(df), by = 2) : 'to' must be of length 1....what does it mean? Also just to clarify...df means degrees of freedom?

Comment: Nope, `df` is the name of your `data.frame` (`data` in your case I suppose).