# Multiple columns of data and getting average R program

Tags: r, list, average, mean

I asked a question like this before but I decided to simplify my data format because I'm very new at R and didnt understand what was going on....here's the link for the question [How to handle more than multiple sets of data in R programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14983347/how-to-handle-more-than-multiple-sets-of-data-in-r-programming)

But I edited what my data should look like and decided to leave it like this..in this format...

```
X1.0   X X2.0 X.1
   0.9 0.9  0.2 1.2
  1.3 1.4  0.8 1.4
```

As you can see I have four columns of data, The real data I'm dealing with is up to 2000 data points.....Columns "X1.0" and "X2.0" refer "Time"...so what I want is the average of "X" and "X.1" every 100 seconds based on my 2 columns of time which are "X1.0" and "X2.0"...I can do it using this command

```
cuts <- cut(data$X1.0, breaks=seq(0, max(data$X1.0)+400, 400))
   by(data$X, cuts, mean)
```

But this will only give me the average from one set of data....which is "X1.0" and "X".....How will I do it so that I could get averages from more than one data set....I also want to stop having this kind of output

```
cuts: (0,400]
[1] 0.7
------------------------------------------------------------ 
cuts: (400,800]
[1] 0.805
```

Note that the output was done every 400 s....I really want a list of those cuts which are the averages at different intervals...please help......I just used `data=read.delim("clipboard")` to get my data into the program

Comment: possible duplicate of [R Grouping functions: sapply vs. lapply vs. apply. vs. tapply vs. by vs. aggregate vs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3505701/r-grouping-functions-sapply-vs-lapply-vs-apply-vs-tapply-vs-by-vs-aggrega)

Comment: The biggest problem for you is the structure of your data. Use `dump(head(data, 10), "")` and post it in here. Whenever you place a question, be sure we can reproduce it. Share a bit of your data and we'll deal with it. Afterwards, [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3505701/r-grouping-functions-sapply-vs-lapply-vs-apply-vs-tapply-vs-by-vs-aggrega) can help you, just as @mnel suggested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a little bit confusing what output do you want to get.

First I change colnames but this is optional

```
colnames(dat) <- c('t1','v1','t2','v2')
```

Then I will use `ave` which is like `by` but with better output. I am using a trick of a matrix to index column:

```
matrix(1:ncol(dat),ncol=2)  ## column1 is col1 adn col2...
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    3
[2,]    2    4
```

Then I am using this matrix with `apply`. Here the entire solution:

```
cbind(dat,
      apply(matrix(1:ncol(dat),ncol=2),2,
     function(x,by=10){      ## by 10 seconds! you can replace this 
                             ## with 100 or 400 in you real data
     t.col <- dat[,x][,1]   ## txxx
     v.col <- dat[,x][,2]   ## vxxx
     ave(v.col,cut(t.col, 
                   breaks=seq(0, max(t.col),by)),
         FUN=mean)})
  )
```

**EDIT** correct the cut and simplify the code

```
cbind(dat,
     apply(matrix(1:ncol(dat),ncol=2),2,
           function(x,by=10)ave(dat[,x][,1], dat[,x][,1] %/% by)))
   X1.0   X X2.0 X.1       1         2
1   0.9 0.9  0.2 1.2  3.3000  3.991667
2   1.3 1.4  0.8 1.4  3.3000  3.991667
3   2.0 1.7  1.6 1.1  3.3000  3.991667
4   2.6 1.9  2.2 1.6  3.3000  3.991667
5   9.7 1.0  2.8 1.3  3.3000  3.991667
6  10.7 0.8  3.5 1.1 12.8375  3.991667
7  11.6 1.5  4.1 1.8 12.8375  3.991667
8  12.1 1.4  4.7 1.2 12.8375  3.991667
9  12.6 1.8  5.4 1.2 12.8375  3.991667
10 13.2 2.1  6.3 1.3 12.8375  3.991667
11 13.7 1.6  6.9 1.1 12.8375  3.991667
12 14.2 2.2  9.4 1.3 12.8375  3.991667
13 14.6 1.8 10.0 1.5 12.8375 10.000000
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer agstudy....but when I'm typing this code...is it all in a single line??

Comment: @MarcoDeNiro there was a browser line in my solution. I remove it. you  copy and paste the line beginning with `cbind` this should work if you data.frame is called dat

Comment: thanks again...but would u be able to tell me how I'm getting this error Error: unexpected symbol in "cbind(data,apply(matrix(1:ncol(data),ncol=2),2,function(x,by=10){t.col <- data[,x][,1]v.col"

Comment: @MarcoDeNiro I add my dat..test the solution with this data.

Comment: I'm getting a new error this time which is so weird: Error in cut(t.col, breaks = seq(0, max(t.col), by)) : 
  object 't.col' not found

Comment: @agstudy, you should modify the "breaks" in your `cut` argument. Maybe something like `breaks = seq(0, signif(max(t.col), digits = 1) + by`. Notice that rows 6-13 in your current output for the first column are the same as the input because the `cut` that you use doesn't capture them as belonging in the same group.

Comment: @AnandaMahto thanks. This part is really confusing in the question of the  OP. He talks about every 100s then he writes 400 ... Whatever, I simplify my answer.