# R programming transfering data from excel with missing values to R

Tags: r, excel, edit, na, delimited

So I have an excel spreadsheet with NA values....What is the best way to copy the data and put it in R...I usually use `data=read.delim("clipboard")...`. But because of those missing values....I keep getting this error

```
Error in if (del == 0 && to == 0) return(to) : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

What are the possible ways I can get rid of this error?...I tried putting zeros instead of NA values but that kinda screws up the what the code is doing

Heres the link of the code that I'm using [R programming fixing error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15018668/r-programming-complicated-way-of-getting-averages-means-and-fixing-error....it) was really helpful for my data problems.
I was gonna post the whole set but theres a limit of 30000 characters

Comment: Can You give some lines of your data to reproduce the error?

Comment: Here is some of my data

Answer (score 4):

You need to set option `fill` to TRUE  , This will let you in case the rows have unequal length, to  add NA fields.

```
   read.table(fileName,header=TRUE,fill=TRUE)
```

fileName here is your excel file path. for example filename ='c:\temp\myfile.csv'.

This should work also with `read.delim` which is a wrapper of read.table. You can  give read.table a string , but you set the text argument not the file one. For example:

```
read.table(text = '    Time Speed   Time    Speed
0.8 2.9 0.3 2.7
1.3 2.8 0.9 2.7
1.7 2.3 2.5 3.1
2.0 0.6 
2.3 1.7 13.6    3.3
3.0 1.4 15.1    3.5
3.5 1.3 17.5    3.3',head=T,fill=T)

  Time Speed Time.1 Speed.1
1  0.8   2.9    0.3     2.7
2  1.3   2.8    0.9     2.7
3  1.7   2.3    2.5     3.1
4  2.0   0.6     NA      NA
5  2.3   1.7   13.6     3.3
6  3.0   1.4   15.1     3.5
7  3.5   1.3   17.5     3.3
```

Comment: By file do u mean the name of my excel spreadsheet?...or simply the name of my data frame

Comment: Can you tell me why I got this error? Error: unexpected input in "file <- C:\"....my file location is C:\Users\Marco\Documents\value.csv

Comment: How do u get the text argument??

Comment: What happens when the missing data isn't at the right end of the row?

Comment: @ClaytonStanley whatever the position of the missing data, it will be filled with NA.

Comment: @MarcoDeNiro you get an error because of \ , replace them by /.Something like 'c:/temp/...'

Comment: @MarcoDeNiro the text argument just to show you that it works. You can copy and paste from excel..